# MATLAB: Creating a matrix from for loop values?

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix

I have the following code:

```
for i = 1450:9740:89910
    n = i+495;
    range = ['B',num2str(i),':','H',num2str(n)];
    iter  = xlsread('BrokenDisplacements.xlsx' , range);
    displ = iter;
    displ = [displ; iter];
end
```

Which takes values from an Excel file from a number of ranges I want and outputs them as matricies. However, this code just uses the final value of displ and creates the total matrix from there. I would like to total these outputs (displ) into one large matrix saving values along the way, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: enable displ as empty before the for loop and remove `displ = iter;` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know the size of the block of data you are reading, you can make your code much more efficient as follows:

```
firstVals = 1450:9740:89910;
displ = zeros((firstVals(end) - firstVals(1) + 1 + 496), 7);
for ii = firstVals
    n = ii + 495;
    range = sprintf('B%d:H%d', ii, ii+495);
    displ((ii:ii+495)-firstVals(1)+1,:) = xlsread('BrokenDiplacements.xlsx', range);
end
```

Couple of points:

1. I prefer not to use `i` as a variable since it is `built in` as `sqrt(-1)` - if you later execute code that assumes that to be true, you're in trouble
2. I am not assuming that the last value of `ii` is `89910` - by first assigning the value to a vector, then finding the last value in the vector, I sidestep that question
3. I assign all space in `iter` at once - otherwise, as it grows, Matlab keeps having to move the array around which can slow things down a lot
4. I used `sprintf` to generate the string representing the range - I think it's more readable but it's a question of style
5. I assign the return value of `xlsread` directly to a block in `displ` that is the right size

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I couldn't get this to work, the first block of the matrix was empty, all zeroes

Comment: Yes there was a mistake in my code; I apologize - edited the answer to get rid of the empty block- see indexing of `displ` when I assigne after the `xlsread`.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
displ=[];

for i = 1450:9740:89910
    n = i+495;
    range = ['B',num2str(i),':','H',num2str(n)];
    iter  = xlsread('BrokenDisplacements.xlsx' , range);
    displ = [displ; iter];
end
```